# HTML/CSS id tag not linking to css #id

Tags: html, css

I have something like:

```
<div id="5.5a">
    <p >First Div</p>
</div>
```

and my CSS has:

```
#5.5a { 
    color=blue;
}
```

Shouldn't the id="5.5a" link to my CSS #5.5a? (Other parts of CSS work so my  tag is right)

Comment: Why is there a `/` in front of the selector?

Comment: Stack overflow got rid of my # and headered the rest of text.

Comment: @BDN You don't need to escape it, you need to submit your code on a new line.

Comment: Thanks guys! The problem was id didn't like numeric starting names. The : was right too (jumping between 3 languages atm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `id`, like a `class`, in CSS should not start with a numeric character (it can, if you want, but it needs to be appropriately escaped) and *cannot* have a `.` in its `id`, since the `.` indicates that the following sequence of (valid) characters is a new class-name.

Further, the property-value assignment in CSS is to use a colon (`:`) not an equals (`=`):

That said, if you *must* use it as-is:

```css
#\35\.5 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span id="5.5">Demo</span>
```

Comment: I think the dot just would have to be escaped like any other “special” character, then it should work.

Comment: For reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id "ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")"

Answer (score 2):

CSS requires colons, not equals signs:

```
#yourIDname {
    color: blue;
}
```

Further, IDs CANNOT start with numbers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2756409) for more info.

I think it is technically OK to have decimals in IDs, but you probably want to avoid them, because they are invalid for class names, and you run the risk of confusing #5.5a for ID `5` with child class `5a`.